# IE7 "Unable to get value of the property"... but it is defined...?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7

I'm not sure what is happening here but this code, which was previously working, has started pulling bugs in IE7: "SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'items': object is null or undefined". The weird thing is that i look at it in F12 and you can see bellow, it clearly can read the object...?

[image]

Am I in the IE7-twilight-zone or is the F12 thing using IE9's engine where everything is fine...? If i press play it goes on to fail. I'm not sure where to start here. Basically the script loops over some JSON it got from an AJaX request.

Anyone seen anything like this before?

Comment: Sorry, there isn't enough information here to answer this. Unless you get lucky and someone happens to know about some IE issue that you hit.

Comment: AH! I realised that i added indexOf to the array prototype to fix another bug and now its trying to loop over the function as a item in the array.

Comment: You can try console.debug or something similar to see if it's get the right value